# Gridviews anidados c#-programación n capas

Tags: c#, sql-server

espero puedan ayudarme con mi caso.

Tengo dos tablas : Header y Header_Detail, lo que pretendo hacer es una tabla anidada,algo parecido a la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que me puedan orientar en la creación de un nested gridview. Cabe resaltar que estoy usando Sql server, c#, windows form y programación en n capas.

Answer (score 1):

Para eso no te va a servir el datagridview pues no tiene funcionalidad de master-detail.

Tienes varias opciones:

1.- Utilizar (o crear) un control de terceros. Hay suites de controles como las de devexpress que incluyen controles con grids que tienen esa funciinalidad, pero son caras. También hay controles que sin gratuitos, por ejemplo este: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195423/DataGridViewExtension

2.- Utilizar el grid de WPF, ya que este contiene la funcionalidad de master-detail, hay formas de usar controles de WPF  en Winforms.

3.- Poner los detalles en otro grid, y que cada vez que el usuario seleccione un renglón en el grid principal actualizas el grid secundario con los detalles.

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu respuesta, con respecto a la opción 3,tendrías algún ejemplo de como sería el codigo javascript que me imagino debe ser necesario para realizarlo ¿verdad?